# How do you add more than one element to a Matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, legend, linegraph

I can't seem to figure out how to add more than one element to the legend of my line graph. I've attached my graph here, and any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
fig1 = figure()

ax0 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line0 = ax0.plot(ln_xdata0, ln_ydata0, '_-', label = "Sweden Crime Rate")
ylabel("Sweden Crime Rate")
xlabel("Year")


ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, sharex = ax0, frameon = False, label = "Sweden Population Growth (in millions)")
line1 = ax1.plot(ln_xdata1, ln_ydata1, 'xr-', label = "Sweden Population Growth")
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax1.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ylabel("Sweden Population Growth (in millions)")


plt.title("Sweden Crime Rate and Population Growth")

plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.show()
```

And [my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlXwn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're plotting on two separate axes so when you call `plt.legend()` it's only taking the most current axis. You can get around this by creating [proxy artists](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) and adding them to the legend manually:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import lines so we can create Line2D instances to go into the legend
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

line0 = ax.plot(range(20),range(20), 'ob-', label = "Sweden Crime Rate")
ax.set_ylabel("Sweden Crime Rate")
ax.set_xlabel("Year")

# setup the second axis
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel("Sweden Population Growth (in millions)")
# plot the second line
line1 = ax2.plot(range(10),range(10), 'xr-')

plt.title("Sweden Crime Rate and Population Growth")

# Create proxy artists to add to the legend
red_line  = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='red', marker='x', markersize=8, label='Sweden population growth')
blue_line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='o', markersize=8, label='Sweden crime rate')

# Add the created lines to the legend
plt.legend(handles=[red_line, blue_line], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

As a side note, I used `twinx()` here to set up the second axis, [checkout the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-twinx). Using proxy artists in this way gives you more flexibility in what you present in your legend. Here's the output (obviously not the real data):

[image: plot]